# Datatable fnCellRender doesn't render

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to render some fields before exporting to excel in my function I am doing like this;

```
"tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "assets/global/plugins/data-tables/tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [ {
                    "sExtends": "xls",
                    "sButtonText": "Excel",
                    "fnCellRender":function(sValue,iColumn,nTr,iDataIndex){
                        console.log(sValue);
                        //console.log($(sValue));
                        return sValue;
                    }
                }, {
                    "sExtends": "print",
                    "sButtonText": lang.L_PRINT,
                    "sInfo": lang.L_PRINT_DESC,
                    "sMessage": "Metrics"
                }]
            }
```

So when I uncomment

```
 console.log($(sValue));
```

it returns just first and second column which doesn't include any html tag inside. But when it finds a value that have html tag it stops.

ex - this gets the valu

```
 <td class=" sorting_1">201408</td>
```

this doesn't

```
 <span style="text-align:right;display:block;width:100%">121.25</span>
```

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this I found it much easier to just write the data into the CSV and see the format so I could then choose how to parse.

When you use the `fnCellRender` property TableTools will not do any parsing of the HTML anymore. I would expect that you would see the raw data in the console window some of which would be HTML I assume and others just values.

When it's HTML you can use JQuery to extract the values or a regular expression. E.g

```
if ($(sValue).prop("checked")) {
       return "TRUE";
} else {
       return "FALSE";
}
```

or in your case

```
return $(sValue).val();
```

Some research I used:
[TableTools background and good discussion with links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675473/remove-span-from-column-on-xls-export)

[TableTools Reference API](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options)