# Remove <span> from column on XLS export

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

I have a working jQuery DataTable (https://www.datatables.net/) using the TableTools plug-in with `<span>` elements in every row of one of the columns.

On clicking the export button, I would like to hide/remove the `<span>` elements from the exported file. Not remove the whole columns, but just the `<span>` elements within that column.

How can I achieve this? I understand how to remove an entire column from the export, but I have not found a way to remove particular elements from the export.

Thanks

**UPDATED**

```
    "oTableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "/public/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
        "aButtons": [
            {
                "sExtends": "print",
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "copy",
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "csv",                   
                "fnCellRender": function ( sValue, iColumn, nTr, iDataIndex ) {
                    return sValue;
                 }               
            }
        ]
      }
```

I have the `fnCellRender` in place, I'm just not sure what the best way is to strip out `<span>` elements.

Comment: In my tests, latest TableTools already strips HTML tags in CSV file. What version of DataTables and TableTools are you using?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com i've tested it with `TableTools 2.2.4` and it doesn't.

Comment: @Kstro21, see my answer and example below. In order for TableTools to strip HTML tags by default, `fnCellRender` must be removed.

Comment: Didn't any of the answers help to solve your issue? still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `fnCellRender` option of a button, from the docs:

> Used to modify the data that has been read from the table through the fnGetTableData API method (used for exporting data). This allows pre-processing of the data before exporting it - for example stripping certain parts of the HTML or postfixing other data.

Read all the options [here](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/button_options). Also read the `aButtons` option at initialisation [here](http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation). The idea is define the buttons that `TableTools` will use and in the button definition use the `sExtends` option to extend a `TableTools` button behaivor.

Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "TableTools_files/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends":    "csv", //extend the default csv
                    "fnCellRender": function ( sValue, iColumn, nTr, iDataIndex ) {
                        if ( iColumn === 5 ) {
                            //feel free to modify the value here
                            return sValue +" TableTools";
                        }
                        return sValue;
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

Read the comments in the example, adjust it to your needs, feel free to comment.

**EDIT:**
Read all this post and use the option that adjust more to your needs
[How to strip HTML tags with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140043/how-to-strip-html-tags-with-jquery)
[Jquery: Strip all specifc HTML tags from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442464/jquery-strip-all-specifc-html-tags-from-string)
[Remove all HTMLtags in a string (with the jquery text() function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889765/remove-all-htmltags-in-a-string-with-the-jquery-text-function)
[JavaScript: How to strip HTML tags from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002111/javascript-how-to-strip-html-tags-from-string)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question to include my "oTableTools" code. I do not know how to strip the `<span>` elements from the string

Answer (score 1):

In my tests, latest TableTools already strips HTML tags in CSV file. See [this example](http://live.datatables.net/tinowuja/3).

In order for this to work you need to remove `fnCellRender`. Apparently, if `fnCellRender` is present, TableTools doesn't do HTML stripping by default.

Also, although DataTables tries to determine column data type automatically, you may want to consider setting that [column type](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) to `html` for searching and filtering.

From the manual:

> When operating in client-side processing mode, DataTables can process
>   the data used for the display in each cell in a manual suitable for
>   the action being performed. For example, **HTML tags will be removed
>   from the strings used for filter matching**, while sort formatting may
>   remove currency symbols to allow currency values to be sorted
>   numerically.
>
> DataTables has a number of built in types which are **automatically
>   detected**:
>
> ...
>
> `html` - Basic string processing for HTML tags
>
> - Sorting - sorted with HTML tags removed
> - Filtering - HTML tags removed from filtering string

Comment: you are damn right, if i remove `fnCellRender` it works. @585connor should upgrade your `TableTools` version or use my answer.

Comment: @Kstro21, your answer is also correct because per documentation `fnCellRender` can be used to **strip certain parts of the HTML**, it gives user more control.

Comment: I updated to the newest stable release of TableTools and removed fnCellRender. It strips the tags, but leaves their contents. I would like to remove the `<span>` elements entirely.

Comment: @585connor, then you definitely need to use `fnCellRender` as @Kstro21 suggested. Can you update your question, post a sample cell content and explain what part you want to be removed, please?